# Python Pandas : move some data in rows as column values using pivot -> unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out a way to easity have new columns corresponding to some rows in a dataframe.

Let's take following pandas data frame :

`df = pandas.DataFrame({'date':[13,13,13,13],'city':['NY','NY','SF','SF'],'timeOfTheDay':['day','night','day','night'],'count':[2,3,4,5]})`

Output :

| date | city | timeOfTheDay | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | NY | day | 2 |
| 13 | NY | night | 3 |
| 13 | SF | day | 4 |
| 13 | SF | night | 5 |

What I would like to get :

| date | city | countDay | countNight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | NY | 2 | 3 |
| 13 | SF | 4 | 5 |

I tried to use pivot_table :

`df.pivot_table('count',['date','city'],'timeOfTheDay')`

Or similarly  :

`pandas.pivot_table(df,index=['date','city'],columns=['timeOfTheDay'],values=['count'])`

And instead of expected result it got me :

```
timeOfTheDay  day  night
date city               
13   NY       3.0    NaN
     SF       NaN    4.0
```

Comment: `df[df['timeOfTheDay']=='night']`.

Comment: This is pivot: `df.pivot_table('count',['date','city'],'timeOfTheDay')`

Comment: Thanks @anky. For some reason it would not work correctly when I test on my side. I run your suggested command and get as a result : city - day - night // NY - 3.0 - NaN // SF - NaN - 4.0

Comment: Could you please update the question with the code you tried and the result you got on your dataframe? Thanks

Comment: @anky just did it ;)

Comment: there must be something wrong here, i did try the same code with the df you posted in the question and I got the correct results, are we sure?

Comment: please consider updating the question instead of links

Comment: Deleted the link here, still I've nothing to add to the question except that I'm sure of the result I get when I test on my side using here above presented data frame

Comment: It was indeed an issue in my dataSet sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for this -

```
>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'date':[13,13,13,13],'city':['NY','NY','SF','SF'],'timeOfTheDay':['day','night','day','night'],'count':[2,3,4,5]})
>>> pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['date','city'],columns=['timeOfTheDay'],values=['count'])
>>> pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.columns.droplevel()
>>> pivot_df.columns.name = None
>>> pivot_df
           day  night
date city            
13   NY      2      3
     SF      4      5
>>> 
>>> 
>>> pivot_df = pivot_df.rename(columns={'day':'countDay','night': 'countNight'})
>>> pivot_df
   date city  countDay  countNight
0    13   NY         2           3
1    13   SF         4           5
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: If the solution helped you , do select it as an answer and upvote

Comment: Hi @Vaebhav. It helps of course but for some reason it does not work. I've run command  : ```pd.pivot_table(df,index=['date','city'],columns=['timeOfTheDay'],values=['count'])
 pivot_df.columns = pivot_df.columns.droplevel()```. What I get as a result are three following lines :  city - day - night //  NY - 3.0 - NaN //    SF - NaN - 4.0

Comment: It was indeed an issue in my dataSet sorry